# Area of the region

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry, area

Let $O(0,0), A(3,0), B(3,2)$ and $C(0,2)$ be four vertices of a rectangle. Let
$$d(P,OA)≤\min {\Bigl(d(P,AB),d(P,BC),d(P,OC)\Bigl)}$$
where $d$ denotes the distance of the point $P$ with the line segments given. Let $S$ denote the region consisting of all those points $P$ inside the rectangle $OABC$ which satisfies the above inequality. Find the area of region $S$.

The last time I asked this question(which was almost a week ago), this problem was put on hold and then closed. I am preparing for an entrance exam and I came across this problem in my book called Co-ordinate Geometry for Jee Mains and Advanced by Dr. S.K Goyal. I had put my best effort to solve this problem but I get a different answer $\frac{9}{5+\sqrt{13}} $. The answer given in my textbook is $4$.Any help for this problem is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your question, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and also show us what you have done

Comment: We can't tell you where you went wrong if you only show us your final result and not how you got there. Your question is likely to get closed again, but you should edit it to show your work and it will likely get reopened.

Comment: And also please edit the title - it is not informative nor related to your actual question.

Comment: sorry guys I meant area of triangle IOA and not IAC

Comment: Did you draw a picture?

Comment: while solving or while typing?

Comment: You should make clear that the solution proposed in the picture is yours.

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that I did not get the right answer(the one given in my textbook)which means my solution could be wrong.

Comment: You need angle bisectors, not circles.  The set of points equidistant from two segments is a (somewhat) complicated shape.

Comment: is it a square with side length 6/(5+sqrt(3)) and a triangle of base length of 3- (6/5+sqrt(3)) and with same height as that of the side of the square?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the inequality right? Shouldn't be $d(P,OC)$ instead of $d(P,AC)$?

Comment: ah damn,sorry my bad .I am such a jerk

Comment: Then I guess I must think about this question from the beginning

Comment: I am extremely sorry if I had wasted your precious time

Comment: Aretino, thanks for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer of $4$ seems wrong.  The entire rectangle has area $6$ and the set of points closer to the bottom edge than the top edge is half the rectangle.  These are contradictory statements.

A quick calculation in my head gives an area of $2$ (a trapezoid of bases $1$ and $3$ and of height $1$).

Comment: Mr. Michael Burr ,I guess the answer given in my text book might have a printing mistake.

Comment: Mr. Michael Burr, can you explain of how you considered a trapezoid with the dimensions that you had mentioned .

Comment: Draw the angle bisectors of the two lower corners along with the horizontal mid-line.

Comment: The typo could be in the inequality symbol.

Comment: @Macavity If that's the typo, it would work out nicely.  Well spotted.

Comment: thanks Mr. Michael Burr for making me realize that points equidistant from 2 sides of a polygon lie along the line of the bisector

Comment: I think the answer is really 2 because the answers given for one or two questions in my book is wrong.

Comment: For more reading, check out the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).